# Aggregate Custom Dimension in Cloudwatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We want to upload metrics like

{dimensions: {country: 'Nl'}, metric_name: customers, metric_value: 12}
{dimensions: {country: 'Uk'}, metric_name: customers, metric_value: 100}

> For metrics produced by certain AWS services, such as Amazon EC2, CloudWatch can aggregate data across dimensions. For example, if you search for metrics in the AWS/EC2 namespace but do not specify any dimensions, CloudWatch aggregates all data for the specified metric to create the statistic that you requested. CloudWatch does not aggregate across dimensions for your custom metrics.

The docs of [cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension) say this. Is there really no way to aggregate them in a Cloudwatch Dashboard?